# Failed to push some refs error in Azure devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I have a project with name A in Azure devops which has readme file only. I created a branch with name mybranch from main. I am trying to push a project with name B from local computer to mybranch in azure.
I am getting failed to push some refs error. I have tried to rebase but that also fails. Please help

Comment: We need more details in order to help you. What do you mean by "project with name A" and "project with name B"? Are these two git repositories? Do they have a shared history or are they completely separate? Are you trying to push them to the same repository in Azure DevOps? Or are you pushing them to separate ones? What is the full error message? Please [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: Both are git repositories. I am trying to push it same repository by creating a branch from main. I get below error. failed to push some refs to mybranch  non-fast forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you already pushed from one of your repos to Azure DevOps. So you need to update your second repo with `git pull` first. If this completes without any errors, then you can do `git push`. Otherwise, you need to resolve the errors (most likely because of a merge conflict).

For more details, you should read about `git remote`, `git pull`, and `git push` as well as merge conflicts.